# How to loop over rows in csv in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, loops, csv, row

I have a csv file that I would like to manipulate in Python 2.7.
My first column has a list of IDs some of which are duplicates.
I have sorted the file by the IDs, so the duplicates occur all together.
I would like  my code to identify if the ID of that `row` is the same like the one of the previous line, and if it is it needs to add the text of column B of the duplicate row to the text of the first row where the ID occurs.
Some values occur more than 2 times. This means that I need to create a loop that once identifies a duplicate manipulates it until all duplicates have been manipulated.

```
   | Col1  | Col2   | Col3         
   | ----- | ------ | -----    
0  | a     | text1  | text1       
1  | b     | text1  | text1 , text2, text3       
2  | b     | text2  |       
3  | b     | text3  |      
4  | c     | text8  | text8
```

My problem is that I cannot select a row in order to build my loops.
Row in the csv package seems to be a list that does not have a unique identification if it's row1, row2, etc.

```
import csv  
with open('dataset.txt', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t")
    for row in reader:
         # i = i+1 # so that the comparison of cola will begin from row2
         cola = str(row[0:1])[2:-2]         
         colb = str(row[1:2])[2:-2]
         colc = str(row[2:3])[2:-2]
         colc = colb
         print cola, " ", colb, " ", colc
         # compare cola of this row to the one of the previous row
         # if cola[r] == cola[r-1]: #
         with open("new.txt", "ab+") as f:
             writer = csv.writer(f, dialect='excel', delimiter='\t')    
             writer.writerow([cola, colb, colc])
```

where I fail is to manipulate each row separately so that I can compare
row[1] or line 1 and line 2 for example that are the same (b).

Any suggestions will be very helpful. I am new to python.

I understand that each `row` is a list but how can I loop through every list the csv file holds?

I would be grateful if you suggested also a better title. This is not just about looping, it's about identifying each row/list uniquely.

Comment: Rows are read in order. The `for row in reader` is what reads each row, in turn.

Comment: how can I identify a specific row through? so that I can compare items of two different rows?

Comment: Is pandas an option for you?

Comment: Not for now, we do not have it installed. Should I assume it's easily done in pandas?

Comment: @QQQs If rows are processed in order, what can be said about their 'identity'? Either keep a counter (which maintains a row-number identity) or first create a list (which has indices - and access across such - implicitly) of rows.